# Find out newly added ALAsset from ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification notification

Tags: ios, gallery, alassetslibrary, alasset

Is there a way to find out which asset was newly added now, from ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification's userinfo?

I've registered to ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification and I receive a call in my call back method. Here I am checking the user info-inside the notification parameter. But I was not able to find out the newly added/deleted asset from user info. Is it really possible to retrieve this data from user info? or should I scan the whole library again to find out which asset was now added

Answer (score 0):

I have fetched some answers from apple document below,

**ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification**

Sent when the contents of the assets library have changed from under the app that is using the data.
In iOS 4.0, the notification’s object is nil.

In iOS 4.1 and later, the notification object is the library object that posted the notification.

In iOS 6.0 and later, the user information dictionary describes what changed:

1. If the user information dictionary is nil, reload all assets and asset groups.
2. If the user information dictionary an empty dictionary, there is no need to reload assets and asset groups.
3. If the user information dictionary is not empty, reload the effected assets and asset groups. For the keys used, see “[Notification Keys.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Notification_Keys)”

This notification is sent on an arbitrary thread.

Hope this helps.